# How to add PTR record for a /16 IP block in BIND using $GENERATE directive?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ptr-record

I'm trying to reverse map a block of IP using PTR record to some special name so their usage can be easily reflected by a simple nslookup.

For example, here's a nslookup result:

```
# nslookup 172.17.201.101
Server:         10.253.33.1
Address:        10.253.33.1#53

101.201.17.172.in-addr.arpa     name = for.internal.use.only.
```

And I learned that I can add PTR record for a /24 block by using `$GENERATE` directive

```
$GENERATE 0-254    $.201.17.172    PTR    for.internal.use.only.
```

So here's the question:

1. Am I doing right exposing infomation of IP address by adding PTR record? Any better idea?
2. If the question above is YES, then how to add PTR record for a /16 IP range? I know I can write 255 lines of `$GENTERATE` directive but any better solution?

Comment: http://www.bind9.net/manual/bind/9.3.2/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2566761 -  `...is used to create a series of resource records that only differ from each other by an iterator.` - looks like `$GENERATE` won't be enough to do what you want as it is more complex than a simple iterater, but I'll let someone who actually knows more about it than me give the final word

Answer (score 4):

If all the entries are the same, you could probably use one zone file with one `$GENERATE` for all zones.

named.conf:

```
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN { type master; file "for-internal-use-ptr.zone"; };
zone "2.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN { type master; file "for-internal-use-ptr.zone"; };
...
```

for-internal-use-ptr.zone:

```
$TTL 1D
@       IN      SOA     ns.your-domain. root.ns.your-domain.  (
                                      1          ; Serial
                                      28800      ; Refresh
                                      14400      ; Retry
                                      3600000    ; Expire
                                      86400 )    ; Minimum
              IN      NS      ns1.your-domain.
              IN      NS      ns2.your-domain.

$GENERATE 0-254 $ PTR    for.internal.use.only.
```

Comment: A better solution compare to mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $ORIGIN variable in your ptr zone file. Here is an example.

```
$ORIGIN 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
$GENERATE 0-254 $ PTR    for.internal.use.only.

$ORIGIN 2.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
$GENERATE 0-254 $ PTR    for.internal.use.only.
```