# Possibility to synthesise resource records in BIND?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ptr-record

is there possibility to synthesise resource records  in BIND, similar as in KnotDNS with following command?

```
synth_record "(forward`|reverse) <prefix> <ttl> \<address>/<nn>";`
```

I need to create PTR records for the IPv6 /64 prefix.

I`m not asking for the $GENERATE directive, as it is having all the records in memory, which would take up to hundreds of EiB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add PTR record for a /16 IP block in BIND using $GENERATE directive?](http://serverfault.com/questions/275400/how-to-add-ptr-record-for-a-16-ip-block-in-bind-using-generate-directive)

Comment: Pretty sure this is a no bud.

Comment: @BillThor As far as I can tell that question and answer only covers dynamically generating a single label. In order to do the same for a `/64` you'd need 16 generated labels. So I don't agree with this being a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent to that functionality built into BIND.

One alternative could be to add records for the addresses which are in use via dynamic updates. For instance you could have a DHCPv6 dhcpd add records on behalf of the clients.

Another option would be to externally (using a script?) generate the necessary records based on contents of other zones and load the result.

Or there's the possibility of using some non-BIND solution, like the one you mentioned in the question.

If you actually want records for the full /64 (sounds unlikely that you would really need that, surely it's a very sparsely used address space), I would suggest some solution where the records are generated on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  You can use $GENERATE to create records.  This has been covered in:

[How to add PTR record for a /16 IP block in BIND using $GENERATE directive?](https://serverfault.com/questions/275400/how-to-add-ptr-record-for-a-16-ip-block-in-bind-using-generate-directive)

Comment: It doesn't really sound like a practical approach for an IPv6 /64 network. Disregarding issues with actually getting the desired format, `$GENERATE` generates records when the zone is loaded. Having all those records in memory doesn't sound like a good idea if you're talking about 2^64 records (18446744073709551616).